How is a question about beliefs a duplicate of a question about sentience?
Question about beliefs: What would it take for an AI to have beliefs?
Question about sentience: At what point can a being be said to have gained sentience?
My own argument inside the first question:

Addressing duplicate charges - Can X have beliefs iff X is sentient/conscious?
This question is not a duplicate of
At what point can a being be said to have gained sentience?. That question is
asking about sentience/consciousness. My present question here is
asking about beliefs. It's not obvious at all that conflating
sentience/consciousness with beliefs is at all justified.
For instance, according to
panpsychism, even
electrons are conscious. Does it follow that electrons have beliefs?
Conversely, a philosophical
zombie might
arguably have beliefs, but by definition it is not conscious.
I'm open to being proven wrong but the conflation of the two seems
false or at least unjustified to me.
See also:

Reddit/AskPhilosophy - Is consciousness a requirement for belief?
Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy - Belief


A supporting comment from a user who thinks the same:

I'm surprised to see so many considering this a duplicate of the question about sentience. Sentience and belief are related, sure, but surely different concepts that can be considered separately. – Jack Aidley


Agreed, these are completely different questions. The other one doesn't even mention AI or beliefs. 4 reopen votes and tag me and I'll be the fifth.

@causative We have 4 reopen votes now ;)

Consider slowing your roll a little!
Let me preface this by saying you're not breaking the rules or doing anything wrong, so in some sense this is immaterial. (Certainly, when VTC-ing, we shouldn't be considering how many questions somebody has asked.)
That said, I counted up the users who appear on the 50 most-recently-asked questions (since Dec 14). Obviously this isn't perfectly representative; it's only a 4-day sample and people get more or less active over time. At the same time, it's maybe useful to compare:



user
# of questions




Syed
15


user80226
7


TheMatrix Equation-balance
5


Victor Bergman
2


Everybody else
0-1



On the one hand, we owe a lot to you (and the other folks on this list) for keeping the site active with new questions! So thank you! (You also do a good job explaining the context for your questions, which I personally really appreciate.)
On the other hand, I think you can probably imagine how this imbalance might feel annoying. While I agree your questions are not duplicates, I think it's fair to call them related, right? Taken as a whole they represent a significant amount of the site's content, so I understand why somebody who isn't particularly interested in the lines of inquiry you're going down would go "ughh, another one of these questions?".
Again--that frustration isn't really a valid reason to mark as duplicate. But when you get down to it, VTC reasons are something decided on by the community and enforced by the community. We come up with them to try and ensure we'll be fair and impartial and hold ourselves to consistent standards, but that only goes so far. In the end it does kinda boil down to "everybody needs to figure out how to play nice and get along." That's a pessimistic view, but on such a small site, I do think it's kinda a practical one.
So if I were in your position, I might consider:

Trying to combine questions when sensible.
Refraining from asking questions if you suspect it won't attract sufficiently different answers.
Spending more time answering other people's questions.
Thanking people for their contributions or explaining how they helped you.
In general, being conscious of when you might be "taking up too much air" in the room.
If you want more philosophy discussion than it feels like this site can handle, consider finding other outlets in addition to the site. E.g. forums, IRL or online book groups, starting a blog or substack, university classes if you can find a way to audit them. (Don't take this as me pushing you away from this site--these are places you could look in addition!)

(I'm aware that you already do many of these! Much of this is advice given to myself when in similar situations, or advice that might be useful to future readers, etc.)
Again, this isn't "rules" advice, it's "social" advice. I think you're totally justified to say "no, nothing I'm doing is against the rules, I'm going to keep doing what I do". However, I think the "social" route might be the best way of achieving your goals.
And for everybody else:
"Everybody needs to figure out how to play nice and get along" goes both ways!
We're all a bunch of prickly jerks spending too much time on a philosophy site and it's natural that we'll annoy each other. That's the quintessential online-community experience. (I'm certain I've annoyed many of you by commenting something like "please define cause, exist, thing, and person, otherwise your question is entirely meaningless".)
In my personal experience, VTCs alone unfortunately aren't a good solution to behaviour you don't like (especially on a small site)--at best, it leads to somebody quitting the site in a huff, but in general it just leads to somebody being upset while continuing whatever annoys you. (Definitely VTCs and VTC-as-dupe have their roles--my point is just that they are rarely sufficient on their own.)

This raises a fundamental question of SE methodology. Should a post be judged on its own terms or should it more broadly consider the poster's style/interests/hangups/etc — in short history.  SE is inconsistent on this — on the one hand ut reifies long term history in terns of badges and above all rep. Yet it discourages or outright disallow ppl to consider other ppl's posting history. See for example.More reified circuitbreakers anyone?

Thank you for doing this census; I found it very enlightening. What I'd be super-curious about is the distribution among posters of questions that were close-voted (regardless of whether or not they were reopened). I know there's a tool (named SEDE?) that people use to run queries like this, but I've got zero experience with it. Maybe someone reading this has got some?

@Rushi I guess I think this contradiction exists everywhere. Most people try not go judge others by their clothes, but recognize that others will judge them for their clothes (and thus try to appear presentable in public)

If you admit that the frustration is not a valid reason to mark the question as duplicate, that is the only thing that matters with respect to the question asked here, and the rest is irrelevant. There is no rule against someone creating new questions. But the code of conduct does say that questions should be closed based on their own merits and nothing else. Emotions are irrelevant.

On second thought, this kind of answer reads as very patronizing. There should be more effort placed on pointing out people incorrectly closing questions than giving social advice to people when they didn’t ask for it. If you acknowledge that there is nothing rule breaking that he is doing, why does it matter? The question asked here is a question about the functionality of the site, not a gateway for patronizing “here’s some social advice for you” type of answers

@Syed There is no rule etc. And the SE-rules are not cast in stone. This is a discussion on that. If you don't allow for some "give" in your usage of the site, you can expect others, in particular the serial VTCers, to likewise not budge from their position. This is not a salutary way of making/participating in a healthy community

@Rushi Marking questions as non philosophical when they clearly are “is not a salutary way of making/participating in a healthy community”

@syed Agreed. You are here 57 days. Ive argued many times, long before that the close reasons as of now are very unsatisfactory. It is for this among many other reasons that I never use my VTC. This does not mean I don't believe questions should never be closed. Rather that the closing mechanism is too broken for me to use.

I can see the argument of the other question having similar answers since belief in common parlance does often involve consciousness. However, there are plenty of people that think belief does not require sentience and there are interpretations of belief that do not require sentience in philosophy for reasons you mentioned. And even if they did think belief required sentience, they would still be separate concepts. As such, it is not a duplicate either way.
This post, again, highlights an obvious issue of this stack exchange. People are closing questions for reasons incorrectly, time and time again. How long will people continually have to post a question here to get a second look when this is done at this point pretty much every day?
Many of the recent questions that were incorrectly closed show an obvious lack of knowledge on the close voters’  part. And unless it stops being a free for all where any student who has no knowledge of philosophy can still close questions, this is doomed to fail.
I also don’t think it’s a surprise that almost all of the highest voted questions were posed many years ago, indicating a general lack of viewership of this site now, for obvious reasons.

I would recommend to change the rules of the site to make it explicit that all questions on LLMs are off-topic unless they ask about a philosopher who wrote on the topic of LLM/AI/computer mental properties. As in, "According to philosopher XYZ, LLMs have belief, can you explain ..."
Anything else will flood this site with low quality content, as anyone can copy all questions on mind to be about computers/software/Ai/LLMs, and very little written philosophy exists, causing plenty of speculation and semantically weak answers.
Even worse, "ChatGPT" is not a single thing that can be talked about, since in every version drastic changes are made by the company providing this app, not just exchanging the underlying LLM, but also the supporting infrastructure. Questions would need to be asked and answered by experts in both philosophy and in computer science to have any value at all, but even that would not help with content again very rapidly, making every answer worthless the next year.
It's almost as bad as asking "Is it raining in New York today?" on any Q&A site, or "what's today's date?". ChatGPT is not some immutable tangible thing that philosophers could even write about.
Or formulate a single question that deals sufficiently with all aspects of mind to be able to close all other such questions as duplicates.

"Or formulate a single question that deals sufficiently with all aspects of mind to be able to close all other such questions as duplicates." - I'm open to proposals about this. Any ideas?

There’s tons of philosophy on AI. You just haven’t bothered to look. And it’s a growing field

I don't think either the questions or answers on AI are obviously lower quality than others, but it's also very closely tied to questions that have been part of Philosophy since its earliest days. AI gives a tangible modern framing for looking at these questions, but the questions are as a valid (or not) as ever.

I specifically said: "unless they ask about a philosopher who wrote on the topic of LLM/AI/computer mental properties". And yes, both the questions and the answers are obviously lower quality than the average.

I would push back on this a little.  AI is a fascinating and deeply philosophical topic, not because it is about minds and thoughts but because it reframes many of the existing discussions about language and reference which are foundational to philosophy, but often difficult to break into without extended study.  I think, as ever, the casual understanding of the self and the practice of thinking makes this more difficult to address to the general public, whose questions may seem superficial and introductory, but surely this is a good platform for answering such questions, if there is one.

I don't disagree, but the issue about question and answer quality remains. Let me start a new thread instead.

If it wa true that questions and answers are of lower quality then SE's usual mechanisms of downvoting and flagging in egregious cases should suffice to handle it. I don't see that justifies a ban on an important modern topic.
